# How can I refresh a page when clicking on a link

Tags: jquery-mobile, tabs, refresh

I have some tabs on a page (using jquery mobile). However, when I change tabs I would like to refresh the page.

This is what I have in my page:

```
<li><a href="#" data-icon="arrow-r" data-tab-class="tab-info">Info</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-icon="arrow-r" data-tab-class="tab-insights">Insights</a></li>
```

I've tried adding a js reload to my href like this:

```
<li><a href="#" data-icon="arrow-r" data-tab-class="tab-info">Info</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:history.go(0)" data-icon="arrow-r" data-tab-class="tab-insights">Insights</a></li>
```

However, this reloads the page and places you back on the first tab.

Answer (score 2):

To refresh the current page, use the below code.

```
$('.selector').on('click', function () {

 // get ID of the current page
 var refreshpage = '#' + $.mobile.activePage[0].id;

 // this will refresh the same page
 $.mobile.changePage(refreshpage, {
  allowSamePageTransition: true
 });
});
```